# CSS Full height container inside other full height container with scrollable list

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to achieve the following:
The page has a header and then a content container which takes up the remaining vertical space. Inside the content container is another header and content container which should also fill the remaining height. The inner content container may have more content than the height, in which case it should scroll vertically.

I tried to achieve this with flexbox, but for some reason the long list overflows and does not scroll. I get close by setting `overflow-y: auto` on the `.content` container, but then the inner headline also scrolls, which is not what I want. I only want the content of the `.inner-content` container to scroll.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.header {
  background-color: black;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.heading {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.inner-content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.scrollable-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.scrollable-content ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.preview img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Foo bar baz</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="heading">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <div class="inner-content">
      <div class="scrollable-content">
        <ul>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="preview">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1574001412492-7555e61a9b53?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .scrollable-content add height or max, min height then it will scroll

Comment: as said nisha, you need to have an height if you want to scroll. Problem here is you have an height of 100vh for the container only, nothing for any others div. With the flex display, elements in inner-content will stretch its height. You could use a grid instead of flex, simple grid for the outer (2 rows, 1 col), and inside the 2nd row another (nested) simple grid. Grid is a 2 dimensions, flex only 1

Comment: Thank you for your insights, unfortunately I do not want to set an explicit height but have it depend on the screen height (this is why there is 100vh on the outer element).

@pierfarrugia Using a grid does not seem to work: https://xogkz3.csb.app/

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

you have 100vh but it's for outside container.

scrollable-content is 5 levels deep in the structure. Can you put height for header? At least 1 height for inner element could work.

In the snippet, I put:

- header height at 100px (in a css var, but could be used as 100px as well)
- content height is so 100vh - 100px: we have a 'real' height for content
  -inner-content height is: calc 100% (content height) minus 2.5rem: h2 is 2rem with a bottom margin of 0.5rem
- scrollable-content has a max-height of 100% with overflow-y auto

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

 :root {
  --header-height: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.header {
  background-color: black;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 800px;
  height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height));
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.heading {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.inner-content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  max-height: calc(100% - 2.5rem);
}

.scrollable-content {
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.scrollable-content ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.preview img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Foo bar baz</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="heading">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <div class="inner-content">
      <div class="scrollable-content">
        <ul>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="preview">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1574001412492-7555e61a9b53?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```